# como receber dados dinâmicos de um form e gravá-los no BD

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

a minha dificuldade acontece porque criei um grid dinâmico onde gero linhas sequenciais para inclusão de produtos, assim não tenho os nomes dos input fixos tradicionalmente.

Neste caso eu vou atribuindo numeração sequencial de acordo que insiro as linhas.

Ex:

VOU FOCAR SOMENTE NO CAMPO PRODUTO, POIS O OUTROS VÃO SEGUIR A MESMA CONFIGURAÇÃO

e quando vou receber estes valores nao consigo ler os dados ...

```
$COMPRAS = NEW Compras();


$total              = $_GET['hidden_total'] ; // recebo o valor total da compra
$linha              = $_GET['hidden_linha'] ; // recebo o numero de linhas de produtos inseridos

for ( $i = 1 ;  $i <= $linha ;  $i ++ ) { 

  $produto.$i       = strtoupper($_POST['produto'.$i]) ;
  $qtd.$i           = $_POST['qtd'.$i] ;
  $valor.$i         = $_POST['valor'.$i] ;


  $COMPRAS->produto.$i($produto.$i);
  $COMPRAS->qtd.$i($qtd.$i);
  $COMPRAS->valor.$i($valor.$i);

}
```

e a classe recebe os dados desta forma ...

```
public function produto($produto)       {   $this->produto = $produto; }

public function qtd($qtd)               {   $this->qtd = $qtd; }

public function valor($valor)           {   $this->valor = $valor; }



### INSERT DE PRODUTOS ### x_produtos_cadastro -> x_produtos_cadastro_ok 

public function insert(){

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO $this->table ( produto,qtd,valor )
    VALUES  ( :produto,:qtd,:valor )";


    $z = DB::prepare($sql);

    //$z->bindParam(':usuario'          , $this->usuario);

    $z->bindParam(':produto'        , $this->produto);
    $z->bindParam(':qtd'            , $this->qtd);
    $z->bindParam(':valor'          , $this->valor);

    return $z->execute(); 

}
```

Comment: Por quê não só adiciona `[]` no nome do campo e trata os valores com o *array* que receber?

Comment: porque na implementação tive de fazer varios controles e até chegar aqui utilizei contadores.

Comment: dentro do grid faço o calculo de tudo, ordeno os produtos, outras funcionalidades, etc .... enfim, tive de utilizar contadores e agora me resta finalizar e salvar tudo no no BD